# How to save img src and span text from child div if checkbox is checked with javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I save IMG src and span text from a child div using Javascript? The data should be saved in two global variabels.

Look at my html/javascript code here http://jsfiddle.net/8LW6Q/7/

```
<div class="parentBox">
<img id="img_1" src="pic1.png" alt="Small pic" class="notChecked">

  <div class="childBox">
<img src="pic1.png" alt="Bigger pic">
 <input type="checkbox" data-img="img_1" onclick="javascript:funCalled(this)"/><span>Sample picture</span>  
    </div>
</div>


<div class="parentBox">
<img id="img_2" src="pic2.png" alt="Small pic" class="notChecked">

<div class="childBox">
            <img src="pic2.png" alt="Bigger pic">
  <input type="checkbox" data-img="img_2"  onclick="javascript:funCalled(this)"/><span>Sample picture</span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

The IMG src in and span tag in childBox should be saved in the global variable imgSrc and imgSpan if the checkbox is checked.

I guess I need a for loop to collect the information from the childBoxes but I have no idea how to get in every childBox to collect it (if it checked). No Jquery.

The function funCalled can be untouched. I want a new function that actives when I push a button.

```
<input type="button" value="show selected pics" onclick="function"/>
```

Look at the Jfiddle for html and javascript code.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Check my answer below. One other qustion, do you want to remove it from the array, if you uncheck?

Comment: Yes it should be removed from the array then. Thanks so much for you help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UkUbuJU/5/edit)**:

```
var imgObj = {};
function funCalled(obj) {
var el = document.getElementById(obj.getAttribute('data-img'));
if (obj.checked) {
  el.className = "checked"; 
} else {
  el.className = "notChecked";
  }
 }

function addMe(obj){
var el = document.getElementById(obj.getAttribute('data-img'));

imgObj[el.id]= imgObj[el.id] || {};
imgObj[el.id].imgSrc = imgObj[el.id].imgSrc || [];
imgObj[el.id].imgSpan = imgObj[el.id].imgSpan || [];

var parent = el.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('childBox')[0],
 imgSRC = parent.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src,
 spanTXT = parent.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;

if (obj.checked) {
    imgObj[el.id].imgSrc.push(imgSRC);
    imgObj[el.id].imgSpan.push(spanTXT);
 } else {
    var imgIx = imgObj[el.id].imgSrc.indexOf(imgSRC),
        spanIx = imgObj[el.id].imgSpan.indexOf(spanTXT);
        imgObj[el.id].imgSrc.splice(imgIx);
        imgObj[el.id].imgSpan.splice(spanIx);
    }

console.log(imgObj, imgObj[el.id].imgSrc, imgObj[el.id].imgSpan);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to get it in two functions? so the funCalled is untouched. So the img src and img span collects when I click on a button? Look at my edit in the original post.

Comment: what do you mean? were would you call the func to collect if not from funCalled?

Comment: The funCalled function is only to change the class for the parentDiv. But i may be call it from a input button from HTML and display the selected pictures and span tag in a new windows for example? <input type="button" value="show selected pics" onclick="javascript:newFunction()"/>

Comment: Do you understand? :) Thanks

Comment: OK, i have updated my answer. Let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks so much Alex. But I guess function funCalled doesn´t work now? The class doesn't changes.

Comment: I have modified my answer too.

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks! so now it save it to the array list when you push the checkbox?

Comment: Is it possible to save it to two globalvariabels (arraylists). Like one for imgSrc and one for imgSpan

Comment: Yes, but you have two images name the same. so when you delete, you delete both on uncheck. The way I did it, is I broke it down based on the id of the parent. so now if you have two same named images, the only one that gets removed is the one that you click on.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, then please click on the checkbox. Thanks

Comment: Oh okej! Thats not the pictures i will use so they will not be same later.

Comment: ahh, ok. So you could make it global arrays if you want. But remember, if they are global, then anyone can overwrite them in you application by accident. so in that case you should always use objects and namespace it, like I did.

Comment: If I understand the code right so the 
imgObj[el.id]= imgObj[el.id] || {};
imgObj[el.id].imgSrc = imgObj[el.id].imgSrc || [];
imgObj[el.id].imgSpan = imgObj[el.id].imgSpan || [];

is not needed when I have to different pictures?

Comment: Yes correct, you can just use the global array you had before.

Comment: I think the if and console is wrong now. lost in head :( hehe sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you are looking for, but not sure how you wanted the data stored in the arrays, so you might have to change that up a bit.

**JS**

```
function funCalled(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById(obj.getAttribute('data-img'));
    if (obj.checked) {
        imgSrc.push({
            id: el.id,
            src: el.src
        });
        imgSpan.push({
            id: el.id,
            text: document.querySelector('[data-img="' + el.id + '"] + span').innerHTML
        });
        el.className = "checked";
    } else {
        imgSrc = imgSrc.filter(function (val) {
            return val.id !== el.id;
        });
        imgSpan = imgSpan.filter(function (val) {
            return val.id !== el.id;
        });
        el.className = "notChecked";
    }
}
```

**Updated JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wyze/8LW6Q/11/